# :order on Rails 2.3.9 not working at all since I installed Bundler?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, find, bundler

**SOLVED, see below.**

My app is on Heroku and they recently [took a ride of the ".gems"](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/gemmanifest) file to use "Gemfile" with Bundler.

**Note:** *I went back to the old gem system and the problem is still there. Same problem locally too now.*

I made the change and everything seemed to work fine till I notice **:order** was not working anymore.

**In the console**

```
Users.find(:all)
  User Load (13.3ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` 
  User Columns (2.2ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM `users`
```

**And then after if I do**

```
Users.find(:all, :order => "'created_at' ASC")
  User Load (13.3ms)   SELECT * FROM `users`
```

**And will return the same results**

Named_scope and everything using :order doesn't work anymore. I had to hardcode the SQL request using find_by_sql to fix it temporarily.

Any help will be highly appreciated...

Thanks.

Updated:

```
require 'rubygems'
source 'http://rubygems.org'
#source 'http://gemcutter.org'
#source 'http://gems.github.com'

gem 'rails', '2.3.9'
gem "bundler", "~> 1.0.15"
gem "builder", "3.0.0"
gem 'delayed_job', '2.0.7'
gem "hashie", "0.4.0"
gem "httparty", "0.6.1"
#gem "httparty", "0.5.0"
gem 'dalli' , '1.0.2'
gem 'calendar_date_select' , '1.16.1'
gem 'ckeditor' , '3.4.3'
gem 'fastercsv'
gem 'geokit' , '1.5.0'
gem 'hpricot' , '0.8.2'
gem 'will_paginate' , '2.3.14'
gem 'feed-normalizer' , '1.5.2'
gem 'memcached-northscale' , '0.19.5.3'
gem 'mysql' , '2.8.1'
gem 'less' , '1.2.21'
gem 'aws-s3'
gem 'paperclip'

gem 'pdfkit' , '0.4.6'
gem 'icalendar' , '1.1.5'
gem 'sitemap_generator'
gem 'taps' , '0.3.23'
gem 'geo_ip' , '0.3.1'
gem 'i18n'
```

**More examples**

```
User.find(:all,{ :order => "CREATED_AT DESC",:test => ""})
ArgumentError: Unknown key(s): test

User.find(:all,{:order => "CREATED_AT DESC"})
User Load (13.3ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` (no order)

User.find(:all,{ :order => "CREATED_AT DESC",:conditions => "SCORE > 10000"})
User Load (13.3ms)   SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `score` > 10000 (no order again)
```

**More Info**

- Moving back to 2.3.8 did not help
- :conditions works but not :offset
- My other local apps works properly

Comment: User.find(:all, :conditions => ["score > 10000"]) will produce
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (score > 10000).

but User.find(:all, :conditions => ["score > 10000"], :order => :score) produces the same SQL. Order doesn't work.

Comment: I just re-set the app without using bundler and still does the same thing... No idea what it could be now :(

Comment: I edited the post and added the Gemfile (just in case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I found the problem after 4h of hunting.

Turns out I didn't delete the vendors after installing Bundler. One of them was https://github.com/xymbol/active_record_random and screwed up Active Record.

Thanks everyone, particularly @mu is too short